# Setting up the Raspberry Pi as a client on a sever

Tags: python, networking, static-ip

I'm attempting to give my Raspberry Pi a static IP address on an ethernet network that I am controlling from a Windows machine.

I want to be able to send my PI UDP packets directly from my server via a static IP address. Here is how I have attempted to the assign a static IP to the PI and to bind it to an address in the /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.105
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.106

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

And in my Python code:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "192.168.1.105"
UDP_PORT = 8888

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
   data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
   print "received message:", data
```

I am unable to bind to the IP address.

My question is, how can I set up my PI so that I can send messages to it via UDP?

Please let me know if you need anymore information or if I am misunderstanding anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely unlikely that your gateway is `192.168.1.106`

The `/etc/network/interfaces` you have would work (if you entered the correct values), but only by accident because `dhcpcd` disables itself. You would be better to follow the recommended settings, as described in [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697).

The above also explains how to find the correct values.